# cassandra stateful set in kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, statefulset

I've been trying to setup a redundant stateful set in kubernetes with the google cassandra image, as depicted in [kubernetes 1.7 documentation](https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/).

According to the [image used](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/cassandra/image/Dockerfile) It's a stateful set with a consistency level of ONE. 
In my testing example I'm using a SimpleStrategy replication with a replication factor of 3, as I have setup 3 replicas in the stateful set in one datacenter only.
I've defined cassandra-0,cassandra-1,cassandra-2 as seeds, so all are seeds.

I've created a keyspace and a table:

```
"create keyspace if not exists testing with replication = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 }"

"create table testing.test (id uuid primary key, name text, age int, properties map<text,text>, nickames set<text>, goals_year map<int,int>, current_wages float, clubs_season tuple<text,int>);"
```

I am testing with inserting data from another unrelated pod, using the cqlsh binary, and I can see that data ends up in every container, so replication is successfull.
nodetool status on all pods comes up with:

```
Datacenter: DC1-K8Demo
======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.16.0.161  71.04 KiB  32           100.0%            4ad4e1d3-f984-4f0c-a349-2008a40b7f0a  Rack1-K8Demo
UN  10.16.0.162  71.05 KiB  32           100.0%            fffca143-7ee8-4749-925d-7619f5ca0e79  Rack1-K8Demo
UN  10.16.2.24   71.03 KiB  32           100.0%            975a5394-45e4-4234-9a97-89c3b39baf3d  Rack1-K8Demo
```

...and all cassandra pods have the same data in the table created before:

```
 id                                   | age | clubs_season | current_wages | goals_year | name     | nickames | properties
--------------------------------------+-----+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
 b6d6f230-c0f5-11e7-98e0-e9450c2870ca |  26 |         null |          null |       null | jonathan |     null | {'goodlooking': 'yes', 'thinkshesthebest': 'no'}
 5fd02b70-c0f8-11e7-8e29-3f611e0d5e94 |  26 |         null |          null |       null | jonathan |     null | {'goodlooking': 'yes', 'thinkshesthebest': 'no'}
 5da86970-c0f8-11e7-8e29-3f611e0d5e94 |  26 |         null |          null |       null | jonathan |     null | {'goodlooking': 'yes', 'thinkshesthebest': 'no'}
```

But then I delete one of those db replica pods(cassandra-0), a new pod springs up again as expected, a new cassandra-0 (thanks kubernetes!), and I see now that all the pods have lost one row of those 3:

```
 id                                   | age | clubs_season | current_wages | goals_year | name     | nickames | properties
--------------------------------------+-----+--------------+---------------+------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
 5fd02b70-c0f8-11e7-8e29-3f611e0d5e94 |  26 |         null |          null |       null | jonathan |     null | {'goodlooking': 'yes', 'thinkshesthebest': 'no'}
 5da86970-c0f8-11e7-8e29-3f611e0d5e94 |  26 |         null |          null |       null | jonathan |     null | {'goodlooking': 'yes', 'thinkshesthebest': 'no'}
```

...and nodetool status now comes up with:

```
 Datacenter: DC1-K8Demo
======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.16.0.161  71.04 KiB  32           81.7%             4ad4e1d3-f984-4f0c-a349-2008a40b7f0a  Rack1-K8Demo
UN  10.16.0.162  71.05 KiB  32           78.4%             fffca143-7ee8-4749-925d-7619f5ca0e79  Rack1-K8Demo
DN  10.16.2.24   71.03 KiB  32           70.0%             975a5394-45e4-4234-9a97-89c3b39baf3d  Rack1-K8Demo
UN  10.16.2.28   85.49 KiB  32           69.9%             3fbed771-b539-4a44-99ec-d27c3d590f18  Rack1-K8Demo
```

... shouldn't the cassandra ring replicate all the data into the newly created pod, and still have the 3 rows there in all cassandra pods?

... this experience is documented in [github](https://github.com/jtviegas/incubator/tree/master/k8s).

...has someone tried this experience, what might be wrong in this testing context?

super thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that after bringing down the node, you need to inform the other peers from the cluster that the node is dead and needs replacing.

I would recommend some [reading](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html) in order to have a correct test case.

Comment: In addition to this. Best way to do this in Kubernetes is probably to add PreStop hook where you remove the node. More info here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far, but I have to clarify that the circumstance I wanted to simulate was an accidental failure of a specific node. I got the idea that cassandra caters for this specific situation.

Comment: @Horia, thank you, did the reading there, `nodetool removenode` does re-establish the token assignments and replicates the data onto the new nodes replacing the dead ones. Still working in a clearer test scenario, but this has helped a lot.

Comment: ...now I wonder, is there an automated way of removing the node as in `nodetool removenode` ? Has this step to be manual ?